# Issue with troubleshooting an error I am getting

Tags: ruby, hash, each

This is the code I am trying to run which counts the frequency of chars in the array passed to it, and this is the error I am getting *`frequency_string': undefined method`each' for "a":String (NoMethodError)*. I'm not entirely sure what is wrong because this is code that should work and was given to me. Very new to Ruby, and have spent hours trying to solve this on my own. Will take any help I can get.

```
def frequency_string(chars)
    frequencies = {}
    result = ""
    chars.each do |char|
        if frequencies.has_key? char then
            frequencies = 1
        else
            frequencies[char] += 1
        end
    end
    frequencies.each do |char, freq|
        result << char << freq
    end
    return result
end
data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'a', '#', 'b', '#', 'a']
puts "Data 1: " + data1.join(' ')
puts
puts frequency_string(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- the line `frequencies = 1` should be `frequencies[char] = 1`. As it stands, you are converting a hash to the number `1`.
- you have `frequency[char] = 1` and `frequency[char] = 1` reversed.

Here is your corrected code:

```
def frequency_string(chars)
  frequencies = {}
  result = ""
  chars.each do |char|
    if frequencies.has_key? char then
      frequencies[char] += 1
    else
      frequencies[char] = 1
    end
  end
  frequencies.each do |char, freq|
    result << char << freq.to_s
  end
  result
end
data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'a', '#', 'b', '#', 'a']
puts "Data 1: " + data1.join(' ')
puts
puts frequency_string(data1)
  #=> a3b2c2d1#2
```

As you gain experience with Ruby you will find that the language allows you to write operations such as this one with very little code. Here's one way:

```
def frequency_string(chars)
  chars.each_with_object({}) { |char,hash|
    hash[char] = (hash[char] ||= 0) + 1 }.to_a.flatten.join
end
puts frequency_string(data1)
  #=> a3b2c2d1#2
```

This may look complex, but it won't be long before you find this to be more natural and straightforward than what you have written. You don't have to worry about this now; I just wanted to give you a taste of what you can look forward to.

Answer (score 0):

```
chars.each do |char|
    if frequencies.has_key? char then
        frequencies = 1
    else
        frequencies[char] += 1
    end
end
```

should be:

```
chars.each do |char|
    if frequencies.has_key? char
        frequencies[char] += 1
    else
        frequencies[char] = 1
    end
end
```

or

```
chars.each { |char| frequencies.has_key?(char) ? frequencies[char] += 1 : frequencies[char] = 1 }
```

You also can make it like this:

[group_by usage](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
irb(main):038:0> data1.group_by { |e| e }
=> {"a"=>["a", "a", "a"], "b"=>["b", "b"], "c"=>["c", "c"], "d"=>["d"], "#"=>["#", "#"]}
irb(main):041:0> data1.group_by { |e| data1.count(e) }
=> {3=>["a", "a", "a"], 2=>["b", "c", "c", "#", "b", "#"], 1=>["d"]} # it can be an optional if it can meet your demands
```

after improvement：

```
irb(main):053:0> result = ''
=> ""
irb(main):054:0> data1.group_by { |e| e }.each { |e| result += e[0] + e[1].count.to_s }
=> {"a"=>["a", "a", "a"], "b"=>["b", "b"], "c"=>["c", "c"], "d"=>["d"], "#"=>["#", "#"]}
irb(main):055:0> result
=> "a3b2c2d1#2"
```

or use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
irb(main):040:0> data1.group_by { |e| e }.inject('') {|r, e| r + e[0] + e[1].count.to_s}
=> "a3b2c2d1#2"
```